# Ajax CORS get metod can work well but when use post method appear err: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: ajax, post, cors, cross-domain

```
app.post('*', function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:63342",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
    });
    res.send('haha');
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Set-Cookie": ['name=tom'],
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:63342",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
    });
    fs.readFile('info.txt', function (err, data) {
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    })
});
```

why use same way(CORS) to do,get method  can do well,but 
post method can't,err:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMTgt.png)

Comment: You need to handle the CORS preflight OPTIONS request the browser automatically sends on its own before trying your POST request. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851771/access-control-allow-origin-issues-even-on-setting-it-up/45851930#45851930

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the node module cors?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

`app.use(cors());`

Comment: should i do it?  i think cors method is only set  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',and 'get' method do well,why

Comment: Like the readme suggests you can add cors() for single routes like:

app.get('*', cors(), function (req, res) {})